# How to instruct search engines to only display result from subdomain when user is in US?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines, search-results

A client's Shopify site has us.clientsite.com subdomain which is outcompeting clientsite.com which is focused on the rest of the world.

Is there any way to tell search engines to only display the us.clientsite to american users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HREF lang codes to define the site as 'English - US' and then try targeting other search engines using other HREF lang coded landing pages.

There is no way to tell Google to 'target this globally'. If your US site is performing better it's because it's metrics are that much stronger than your general page.

If this is important, then you can attempt a redirect based on an IP geolocation lookup on the server side. Users outside the USA will automatically be redirected to the international page. Or you can give users the option when they land to choose their locale.